# Xamarin.Froms How to create Android like Ios Tab

Tags: xamarin.forms

http://www.androidhive.info/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/android-material-design-tab-layout.png

http://ivomynttinen.com/content/3-blog/20130821-the-ios-7-design-cheat-sheet/tabbar.png

I want to create tab like first image on Ios. How do i achive that?

Comment: iOS UI guidelines require tabs to be at the bottom of the page

Comment: I know that, but some app like YouTube has upper tab.

Comment: As Jason said, in iOS tab bar is at the bottom of the page. If you want to show it at the top of the page you can desing your own tabbar